# [ObjectPromise]1 while trying to add numbers in database discord.js & sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite, discord.js, sequelize.js

So im making /reputation command in discord.js v13, it simply works like: user execute the command -> program finds if the target is already in the database, and if it is - adds 1 to existing value, if it isnt - set value to 1, but when i use it ( target exists in db ) it returns [ObjectPromise]1 in database (no error)

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const Reputation = require('[...]/src/database/tables/reputation.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('reputation')
        .setDescription('Add / view reputation points to the user')
        .addSubcommand(sc => sc
            .setName('add')
            .setDescription('Add reputation points to the user')
            .addUserOption(option => option
                .setName('user')
                .setDescription('Specify user')
                .setRequired(true)))`your text`
        .addSubcommand(sc => sc
            .setName('view')
            .setDescription("View user's reputation points")
            .addUserOption(option => option
                .setName('user')
                .setDescription('Specify user')
                .setRequired(true))),


    async execute(client, interaction) {
        const interactionSubcommand = interaction.options.getSubcommand();
        const interactionTarget = interaction.options.getUser('user');

     switch(interactionSubcommand) {
           case 'add': {
                const [ dbReputation ] = await Reputation.findOrCreate({ where: { id: await interactionTarget.id } });
                const oldValue = Reputation.findOne({ where: { id: await interactionTarget.id } });

                if(dbReputation) {
                    await dbReputation.update({ points: oldValue + 1 });
                } else {
                    await dbReputation.update({ points: 1 });
                }

                await interaction.reply(`:white_check_mark: Successfully added **1** reputation point to ${interactionTarget}`)

            } break;
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't need to use `await` with simple string values, you should use it with promises. `const oldValue = Reputation.findOne({ where: { id: await interactionTarget.id } });` should be `const oldValue = await Reputation.findOne({ where: { id: interactionTarget.id } });`
`